# Javascript querySelectorAll undefined

Tags: javascript

Apologies if this is daft but I'm going a bit mad with this issue i think. I keep getting an undefined error when logging my querySelectorAll to the console. I would like to add a click event on the querySelectorAll selector below eventually once i can work out the issue. All i want is the btn click handler to work when the section has class active.

```
<section class="section test active">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>

<section class="section test">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.section.active .btn');
console.log(btn[0]);
```

This shows undefined.

What i am looking to do is something like

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.section.active .btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 //Do something
});
```

EDIT
Sorry i forgot to add the class section to the section tag

Appreciate any advice

Comment: `.` is a *class selector*, therefore `.section` is looking for the *class* of `section`, rather than a `<section>` element. To select an element by type, you simply avoid prefixing it. For example, `section` would select `<section>`, and so on. Long story short: Drop the `.` before `section` :)

Comment: Thank Tyler, the reason i had the .section was because it was meant to have the class section I forgot to add it :-)

Comment: Cool. That said, you can't do `.addEventListener` on a *collection* of elements, but rather *one* element. You can loop through the collection to apply it to each, or apply it only to the first button for example by doing `btn[0].addEventListener` instead.

Comment: If you get no result from querySelectorAll then there was nothing to select when it was run. When/where was you code executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong(the dot before section), it should be

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('section.active .btn');
```

Also querySelectorAll returns a list of elements, you will have to add the event handler to each element individually.

```
for (var x = 0; x < btn.length; x++){
    btn[x].addEventListener('click', function() {
     //Do something
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Musa i will try the loop you suggest, I actually forgot to add the class section to my section element which i have just amended which is why i was using .section.active

Answer (score 0):

`.section` is targeting elements with the class `section`. You meant to select `<section>` which has class `.active`. To make it work for a NodeList, you need to loop over the returned list, or use `querySelector`

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("section.active .btn");

[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {

  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Do something
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I actually forgot to add the class section to my section element which i have just amended which is why i was using .section.active

Comment: @TylerRoper, thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign the event to a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) vs. one particular element. Won't work. Instead, loop through the collection and individually assign the event to each element as so:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.section.active .btn');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(btn, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="section test active">
  <div class="btn">Active Button</div>
</section>

<section class="section test">
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks Carl for this, I've not used prototype.for.each.call before. Will have to look into this, im fairly new to javascript

Comment: No worries. Being that what you're trying to loop through is an HTMLCollection as I stated before, doing a simple `forEach` won't work (because it's technically not an array). That's why using `call` from the array prototype is necessary here. It's the most browser safe solution. Otherwise, `Array.from(btn)` could also be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You are putting a `.` before `section` which is wrong

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.section.active .btn');
console.log(btn[0]);

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.section.active .btn');
btn.forEach((b)=> {
   b.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Do something
  });
})
```

```html
<section class="section test active">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>

<section class="test">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @md Johirul Islam for this, I actually forgot to add the class section to my section element which i have just amended which is why i was using .section.active